# How to Insert images in WordPress using code

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, attachments, media

I am trying to create a plugin for auto posting. I was able to create new post and then get the attachment for the post. But images are not showing inside the post itself. but if I click on media library and select uploaded to this post, I can see image there.

Can somebody help in achieving the appropriate results.

```
$keywords = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ',$_POST['keywords']);    
$keywords = explode("\n",$_POST['keywords']);
$content = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ',$_POST['content']);

$length = count($keywords);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    $title = $keywords[$i];
    $contentfinal = str_replace("keyword",$title,$content);
    $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $contentfinal,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'tags_input'    => $title
    ); 
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
    echo "$post_id <br />";
    $newkeyword = strtolower($title);

    //upload image
        $filename = "http://www.domainname.com/wp-content/uploads/$newkeyword.jpg";
        echo $filename;
        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id);
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );  
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id);
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function to insert image to a post.

**Note**: The following function will not make the image **"featured image"**. It will just uploaded the image and attach it to the post.

It will return the attachment id if the upload is successful

```
function insert_post_media( $post_id, $url){

        $tmp = download_url( $url );

        $file_array = array();

        // Set variables for storage
        // fix file filename for query strings
        preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpg|jpe|jpeg|gif|png)/i', $url, $matches);
        $file_array['name'] = basename($matches[0]);
        $file_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp;

        // If error storing temporarily, unlink
        if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
            @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
        }

        // do the validation and storage stuff
        $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id, $desc );

        // If error storing permanently, unlink
        if ( is_wp_error($id) ) {
            @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            $error_string = $id->get_error_message();
            echo '<div id="message" class="error">'.$url.'<p>' . $error_string . '</p></div>';
            return $id;
        }

        return $id;            

        //incase you want to get url of the image
        //$src = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
    }
```